# Get return value of reverse geocode

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am iterating through a list of latitudes and longitudes from excel. That works fine, I want to have my codeLatLng function return the street address when I call it in the loop.

The commented code is what I was trying to do inside codeLatLng(). I know I can only do 10 calls to google per second, how would I set my loop up to do this?

Thanks!

```
        function codeLatLng(input) {
            var latlngStr = input.split(",", 2);
            var lat = parseFloat(latlngStr[0]);
            var lng = parseFloat(latlngStr[1]);
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
            geocoder.geocode({
                'latLng' : latlng
            }, function(results, status) {
                document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = results[0].formatted_address + "<br />";
                //return results[0].formatted_address;
            });
        }

        function initialize() {
            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();              
        }   

        function showmethemoney(){  
            var lat, lng, latlng, loc;
            var Excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application"); 
            Excel.Visible = false;
            Excel.Workbooks.Open($("#file").val()); 
            Excel.Active
            //Excel.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
            $("#test").append("<b> " + Excel.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count + " rows in file</b><br/>");
            //10 for testing purposes. I will be going through the entire document
            for (var i=1; i <= 10; i++) {                   
                lat = Excel.ActiveSheet.Cells(i,17).Value;
                lng = Excel.ActiveSheet.Cells(i,18).Value;
                latlng = lat + "," + lng;
                //loc = codeLatLng(latlng);         
                $("#test").append(i + ") " + latlng + " " + loc + "<br/>");                                     
            };  
            Excel.Quit();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide a callback method. The method you provide will be called with two parameters:

- An array of [GeocoderResult](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#GeocoderResult) objects
- A [GeocoderStatus](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#GeocoderStatus)

Inside your callback, you can handle the data returned from the geocoder as you need.

See Geocoder documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Geocoder)

In more details, the geocode method will make an ajax call to the google service. This is asynchronous. As the geocode method is called, the rest of your function continues to be executed. Once the service responds, your callback will be called and the result and status will be passed in parameters. If you want to store the result, you can simply add it to any container that would be accessible for you to use outside.

Comment: Could you provide a small code example? I understand what you are saying in theory but I am still new to js and am trying to grasp callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

Provide a callback to  codeLatLng that will be called on success. Modified code.
Added loop in code I am using setTimeout to loop in bunch of 10 items.

```
  function codeLatLng(input, i, cb) {
                var latlngStr = input.split(",", 2);
                var lat = parseFloat(latlngStr[0]);
                var lng = parseFloat(latlngStr[1]);
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
                geocoder.geocode({
                    'latLng' : latlng
                }, function(results, status) {
                    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = results[0].formatted_address + "<br />";
                   cb( results[0].formatted_address, i, input);
                });
            }
    function showmethemoney(){  
 //your code 
           var i = 1;
           function repeat10(i, max){
                for ( ; i <= max; i++) {                   
                     lat = Excel.ActiveSheet.Cells(i,17).Value;
                    lng = Excel.ActiveSheet.Cells(i,18).Value;
                     latlng = lat + "," + lng;
                    codeLatLng(latlng, i, function (loc, i, latlng ){
                          $("#test").append(i + ") " + latlng + " " + loc + "<br/>");   
                     });         

               } 
             setTimeout(function(){
                  if(i >= maxexcelsize){ return };
                   repeat10(i, i+10);
              }, 100);
            } 
            repeat10(i, i+10);
            Excel.Quit();
        }
```